# Javascript fetch ReadableStream is not slowing down network when being read slowly

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The following example is a very simple fetch snippet that initiates a fetch to a large object and reads from it (in reality it is being transformed and passed to a `Response` object but that doesn't matter).

The problem is that even though the stream only reads 2 chunks, when viewed in the Network DevTools it is obvious that the whole large object gets downloaded:

```js
fetch("http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/200MB.zip").then(response => {
    const networkreader = response.body.getReader();

    networkreader.read().then(data => {
        console.log("read", data.value.length);
    });

    networkreader.read().then(data => {
        console.log("read", data.value.length);
    });

    // networkreader.cancel(); // can't do that
});
```

As expected the read works and only returns 2 chunks of data but in the DevTools the full 200MB is being downloaded. Calling `cancel()` on the stream would stop the download but I can't do that as the stream is handed over to the `Response` object and it will consume data slowly, take a pause, etc. and cancel it maybe after minutes of inactivity.

This happens in the real world when the resource is a video or other streamable data that is consumed via chunked encoding or HTTP/2.

The only workaround I can imagine is using range requests and thus throttling the browser (Chrome in my case) from downloading so much data that will most likely not be used.

If I did something wrong or this is a browser issue please let me know as the range request approach feels rather messy. Thank you.

Comment: The server sends as much of the response as it can, and the browser buffers it until the application reads it. What problem does this cause?

Comment: This is simply the way TCP works. It makes things more efficient, since readers rarely have to wait for data if they process it slower than the sender sends it.

Comment: @Barmar The TCP Window works as intended and is not the problem here: When I have a video consumer attached to a fetch (service-worker) and the video does not autoplay (it only reads the mp4 header) the video uses either chunked content encoding or HTTP/2's data streaming to stop the server from sending more data after the initial header. But after the fetch that it is going through this data streaming meta information is lost and the server keeps sending as many gigabytes of data as it wants with chrome storing the data for future use.

Comment: @Barmar But unfortunately after a seek this "data for future use" gets discarded because the stream gets canceled by the underlying transport system. Thus I'm wasting large amounts of traffic which is especially fatal on mobile devices.

Comment: I have decided to use range requests for now as that will also help with partial caching.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the TCP window. If the application (web browser) reads the data from the network stack into its own buffers, the window never closes.